# Finding all lines that end with \ using Regex

Tags: regex

So I have been beating my head against a wall in trying to find a regex that will suit my need.  I have a list of processes, Files, and folders.  The folders is what I need to find.  The last character of each line will be `\`.

I have tried these,

```
^\\\$

[\s ^]\\\\[\s$]
```

Comment: Can you put a sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Use [positive look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get all `\` which follows newline(`\n`) or at the end.

```
/.*\\(?=\n|$)/g
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/oY6Swk/2)

---

Or as *@CasimiretHippolyte* said in the comment : you can use regex with the multiline modifier(`m`) where you can use start and anchors for a line.

```
/^.*\\$/gm
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/yLuQG0/1)

Comment: @Joshua.Dixon :  glad to help :)

Comment: You can also use `/^.*\\$/gm`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : yes that also works :) added in answer